# Adding an Array to JTable in Java

Tags: java, arrays, user-interface, jtable, row

Since you create the `JTable` with an matrix for data and array for the columns I figured there should be a way to after created the `JTable` adding an array (row). Or how is it meant to add a row with Strings?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot add to a JTable directly, you have to get the underlying TableModel. You get this by calling `JTable.getModel()`. TableModel is an interface, in a standard JTable it's implementation is DefaultTableModel. So you have to cast the underlying TableModel to a DefaultTableModel, and then you can apply `DefaultTableModel.addRow( Object[] )`. (You do, of course, check that the cast is safe and all that).

Answer (score 1):

To change the data displayed by the `JTable`, you need to go through the `TableModel`.

Have a look at the [`JTable.getModel()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#getModel%28%29) method and the methods in the [`TableModel`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableModel.html) interface.

Answer (score 1):

you can add/insert row in JTable like this way

```
table.getModel().insertRow(table.getRowCount(),new Object[]{"hello","50"});
```

here is the tutorial link

http://www.roseindia.net/java/example/java/swing/InsertRows.shtml

Answer (score 1):

there aren't some problem with that, here is [How to Use Tables](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) with nice example, tons of examples [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/CatalogSwing-JFC.htm) and [here](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/javax.swing.table/pkg.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can also create a class of your own which extends **AbstractTableModel** and implement the abstract methods. This class can also contain the array (or whichever collection or data structure you use) and the abstract methods which you implement will use this array, methods such as **getValueAt** and **setValueAt**.
Then you can create a new instance of this class and set the table model of the table to this object. Adding rows to this table is now possible by adding entries/elements to the array.